# How do I permanently delete a .sys driver file (and stop it from coming back) on Windows 11

Tags: windows, drivers, bsod

I'm having an issue with [something](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448340/) (also linked to this question) involving drivers on Windows 11. Basically, to cut a long story short, a .sys driver file is causing a BSOD on boot but every time I delete the .sys file in the `C:/Windows/System32/drivers` folder, it'll then reinstall itself when reboot and then BSOD.

The only way I can bypass this is by going in Safe Mode, which then it works fine.

The driver name is `igdkmd64.sys`.

How do I permanently delete the .sys file and stop it from reinstalling? I have tried deleting the thing using the driver in Device Manager but it keeps coming back. Also, I have tried disabling driver auto-install (Settings > System > About > Advanced device settings) but that didn't help.

Comment: I tried the delete command, didn't delete it still. Well, it did but it's basically the same as deleting it from Device Manager which also didn't work. It'll come back when I restart.

Comment: Just disabling the device should work fine. Usually, it sticks across reboots.

Comment: Alright. But I did delete the thing using the driver, and the driver itself. I got it to boot into the Desktop for about 2 minutes, so I opened Device Manager and the thing using the driver was gone but then it BSOD'd me with `igdkmd64.sys`...

Comment: Hardware is automatically discovered (Plug and Play) and reinstalled. Deleting physical devices in Device Manager is mostly pointless.

Comment: I managed to get it to work, but then I installed the Windows Support thingy from Boot Camp and now it boots and then crashes (WDF_VIOLATION)